# Has anyone else noticed that Android Studio sends a TCP burst when a compile completes?

Tags: android-studio

**Backstory**

I have recently moved to a more rural area for a few weeks. Unfortunately there isn't a fixed internet connection here, so I have been using a 3G modem. Data is expensive in Australia so I have been monitoring what applications use the most data and shutting down everything that I can.

**Question**

I have noticed that I have a peak of network traffic every time Android Studios successfully builds one of my apps. According to the mac Activity Monitor the peak is about 3.2MB. I have tried turning off usage statistics however that doesn't seem to help.

Does anyone know what is causing this network burst and how to stop it?

**More Info**

I have included a [Wireshark dump in a zip](http://db.tt/PoIS4tRg) for anyone interested in taking a look at the packets. I can tell that it is going to Google at the 74.125.237.78 IP. Data is quite expensive here in Australia and I'd like to minimise my cost while I have to use a 3G modem.

Answer (score 2):

Gradle connects to the internet to fetch dependencies and to make sure you have the latest versions of dependencies (if you specified versions as 1.2.+).

If you would like to disable this, in Android Studio 0.5.1+ you can enable Offline Mode by navigating to File->Settings->Gradle->Offline work.

But note that even in offline mode, Gradle will still connect to the internet periodically (every 24 hours) to ensure that dependencies with versions that use '+' are up to date.

Comment: I don't think that was the cause in this case since the project wasn't using Gradle at the time.